# Что делать если бэкграунд покрывает не весь футер в чем проблема?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Что делать если бэкграунд  покрывает не весь футер, в чем проблема?
У меня он покрывает только ту часть которую я укажу в heidth,а если указать с запасом фон далеко в низ уходит, есть ли возможность сделать его "резиновым", что бы растягивался вместе с блоком?
heidth 100% не помогает.

```
 footer{
        max-width: 1630px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        display: block;
        background: #414146;
        line-height: 1.3;
```

Comment: Knurl360259 вставь  код чтобы можно было видеть проблему .

Comment: а точно heidth ?

Answer (score 1):

Ваш код корректно работает в моих браузерах.
Единственное, из-за чего фон может быть не на всю ширину - это ограничение:

```
max-width: 1630px;
```

С высотой блока проблем нет никаких.

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался фон западал за слайдер с позицией absolut.